# Making sure a table entry is unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have  mysql database table for addresses, it contains separate columns for post code / street /town.

How can I make sure a full table entry is unique rather than just one of the columns alone?

Comment: Create a unique key on all of the fields in the table. You'd have to update the key anytime you add new fields to the table, though.

Comment: add unique constraint on post code, street, town. But again there may be duplicates that are hard to identify like XYZ street, XYZ st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql allows you to have a unique key for n number of fields or columns. When you declare this column as unique , mysql checks for the constraint for duplication.
For more info read this [mysql unique key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

"The UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints both provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns."

But, i suggest the front end validation for making the user comfortable (just incase u had not thought of it ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Make a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_key) key on `{post code, street, town}`.

A key can be primary (PRIMARY KEY) or alternate (UNIQUE constraint).

---

BTW, can two different `town`s have the same `post code`? If not, you don't need the `town` in the key. In fact, consider normalizing your model by "extracting" the `town` to a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

A database table may have multiple unique keys, so it will reject any `INSERT` queries that violate the constraints you set in the table.

Simply set the other columns to be unique and you should find that your problem is solved.